      はどういう文字ですか？
コピペすると普通の文字とは違うように表示されるのですが、何が異なるのですか？
文字コード？
フォント？

UTF-8の文字コードで見ると0xF09D9xxxの範囲の文字ですので、数学用英数字記号 というものらしいですね。
この辺の記事が参考になるでしょう。
数学用英数字記号 - Wikipedia
Unicode ［ 数学用英数字記号 ］- Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols -
UTF8 文字コード表 4byte (f09d)
以前のご自身の質問の時と同じような分野(なのか単なるデザイン的なユニークさを目指した？)のサイトを見たのではありませんか？
この  は何ですか？ 普通の C と何が異なるのですか？
